# Intellij IDEA creates multiple process for each debug session?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Every time I hit the debug button in my IDE is create a new process running on the OS.

[image]

Is there a way to configure things so that only one JAVA process can be running on my OS at once when hitting the debug button?

What I know is if I hit the red stop button in the debugging panel that number will decrement.  So long as I remember to stop before hitting the debug button each time I can manage the number of running processes.  But this is easy to forget to do.  In addition, once i have 5-10 running debug sessions it is very tedious to delete them all.  I must go to `Run->Show Running List` and a list of the "VM Connections" appear and I must delete them one by one.  Often this UI component that lists them will simply disappear and I must pull it out again.  Is there a way to end all of these processes at once?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do it OS wide AFAIK, and you wouldn't want it to be that way; how many *other* Java processes may be running that aren't associated with your debug sessions?? (Intellij would be one of them)

What you can do is, in your run configuration settings, set one or more of your configurations to be "Single instance only"; it's a checkbox in the upper right-hand corner of the dialogue. That will force you to kill any running with that config before starting another.

Comment: thanks.  that is exactly what i was searching for.  Regarding the OS, I only mentioned that because I noticed in my activity monitor that I had close to 10 Java processes running that were undoubtedly unstopped debug sessions.

Answer (score 4):

**IntelliJ Idea 2017**

Mark this checkbox:

`Run -> Edit configurations -> Single instance only` (top right corner)

It won't let you run another instance before running the next one.

Comment: `Single instance only` not working for me for some reason even though I enabled it

Comment: @UmerFarooq this will work only if you run the same configuration

Comment: I'm running the same configuration but for some odd reason it's creating new instances everytime I hit play button

Answer (score 2):

from [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 Help /Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-remote.html):

"*IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 Help /Run/Debug Configuration: Remote*

*Common options*

***Single instance only***
If this check box is selected, this run/debug configuration cannot be launched more than once.
Every time a new run/debug configuration is launched, IntelliJ IDEA checks the presence of the other instances of the same run/debug configuration, and displays a confirmation dialog box. If you click OK in the confirmation dialog box, the first instance of the runner will be stopped, and the next one will take its place.
This makes sense when the usage of certain resources can cause conflicts, or when launching two run/debug configurations of the same type consumes too much of the CPU and memory resources.
If this check box is not selected, it is possible to launch as many instances of the runner as required. So doing, each runner will start in its own tab of the Run tool window."

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Intellij IDEA**

For all those who wonder that every time a second java process occur (with ca. 100 MB memory allocation) once a compile/debug/run is executed and only one instance is running: The process is the Compile Server which runs parallel to main IDEA and takes over compilation. Reason for this is lower memory footprint and performance.

[The feature exists since 2012, but was not enabled by default.](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/brand-new-compiler-mode-in-intellij-idea-12-leda/)

Answer (score 0):

All of us in the company have the `IntelliJ Idea` and we all faced this issue after version `2019.2.3`. The solution was unexpected. as You can see in the below picture, there is an item named `On frame deactivation` and the default value was `Update classes and resources`.

In this case, when we were on `debug mode` and we were changing a simple thing and we were  changing the current windows (for example bringing the chrome to front to test the change), for every `deactivation on idea frame` it was creating two processes (one for `building` and one for `hot swap`), so you can imagine how many processes you could end of with. I had personally 12 processes some times!

The answer was changing this value to `Do nothing`. so every time I change a class, I press the `white button` in `debug frame` **manually** and it does the resource refresh only one time.

We tried to change the heap size or other solution and they were ineffective for us.

[image]